# How use '?' in @Query? How use Jsonb of postgres in spring-boot at all?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

How to use ?| operator in postgres query in spring repository? I need to use where in my query for text type column which content json.

```
@Query(value =
        "SELECT * \n" +
        "FROM tbl t \n" +
        "WHERE t.some_ids::::jsonb ?| array['152960','188775']", nativeQuery = true
)
List<Model> getModelsByIds();
```

But that don't work and I catch the next exeception: 
 org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: At least 1 parameter(s) provided but only 0 parameter(s) present in query.

Comment: Indeed, obfuscation layers do make it hard to use the full potential of Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the associated function of that operator instead. Most of the time the obfuscation layers also choke on the `::` cast operator, so you might want to use `cast()` instead:

```
WHERE pg_catalog.jsonb_exists_any(cast(t.some_ids as jsonb), array['152960','188775'])
```

However I think this wouldn't be able to make use of an index defined on `some_ids::jsonb`

You didn't mention how exactly the content of `some_ids` looks like.

If that is a JSON array (e.g. `'["123", "456"]'::jsonb`) then you can also use the contains operator `@>`:

```
WHERE cast(t.some_ids as jsonb) @> '["152960","188775"]'
```

If your JSON array contains numbers rather than strings (`'[123,456]'`) you need to pass numbers in the argument as well:

```
WHERE cast(t.some_ids as jsonb) @> '[152960,188775]'
```

Comment: Thank you. That is what I need. You explained very well. And... could you tell me how to pass the array as param in @Query?

Comment: Tkanks, I resolved it using string_to_array(:ids, ',').